# What does [[ $strin = *[!0-9]* ]] mean in bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm learning bash, in particular regular expressions and I found this in my book:

```
read strin

if [[ $strin = *[!0-9]* ]]; then

   echo "error"

else
   echo "success"

fi
```

My problem is that I don't understand what this regular expression means, in particular I don't understand the '!' in the range.

Comment: Does your book not explain what that snippet of code does?

Comment: That's not a regular expression; it's a pattern.

Comment: it doesn't because its a exercise but it isnt explain it

Comment: sorry chepner, what is a difference? sorry but I 'm beginning studying bash and this example is in the regular expression chapter

Comment: What book are you using? The right-hand side of the `=` takes a literal string or a glob pattern (like what you use for filename matching); regular expressions are used with the `=~` operator.

Comment: See section 2.13 of the POSIX shell spec for details on pattern matching: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13

Comment: @mariorazzu, if a book you're reading describes that as a regex, I suggest replacing it with a better book.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of pattern matching. It succeeds if the value of `string` consists of 0 or more characters, followed a single character that *isn't* in the range 0-9 (i.e., a non-numeric character), followed by zero or more arbitrary characters. In short, the pattern matches anything that contains at least one non-numeric character.

Comment: the '!' in the range says that it doesn't find number, but the '*'?

Comment: The `*` is a pattern metacharacter that matches anything, including the empty string.

Comment: sorry Now I understand

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> [[…]]
>
> [[ expression ]]
>   ....
>
> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), as if the extglob shell option were enabled. The ‘=’ operator is identical to ‘==’. .... Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.

and about Pattern Matching (emphasis mine):

> 3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching
>
> Any character that appears in a pattern, other than the special pattern characters described below, matches itself. The NUL character may not occur in a pattern. A backslash escapes the following character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching. The special pattern characters must be quoted if they are to be matched literally.
>
> The special pattern characters have the following meanings:

....

> […]
>   Matches any one of the enclosed characters. A pair of characters separated by a hyphen denotes a range expression; any character that falls between those two characters, inclusive, using the current locale’s collating sequence and character set, is matched. **If the first character following the ‘[’ is a ‘!’ or a ‘^’ then any character not enclosed is matched.** A ‘-’ may be matched by including it as the first or last character in the set. A ‘]’ may be matched by including it as the first character in the set. The sorting order of characters in range expressions is determined by the current locale and the values of the LC_COLLATE and LC_ALL shell variables, if set.

Comment: @hek2mgl Link-only answers are frowned upon; you can't rely on an external resource to remain available. Relevant quotes from a linked source make the answer more reliable should the external resource disappear.

Comment: @chepner He did say comment not answer. And had I had Charles Duffy's link handy I might have done that. But the reference manual splits the information up and the first section isn't directly linkable.

Comment: No worries, I just said *IHMO* because I thought it might be duplication of information. Plus one for your efforts! ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the POSIX shell specification on pattern matching: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13

---

First, on the asterisks:

> `*`
>   An asterisk is a pattern that shall match multiple characters, as described in Patterns Matching Multiple Characters.

---

Then, on the `[!0-9]`:

> The description of basic regular expression bracket expressions in the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 9.3.5, RE Bracket Expression shall also apply to the pattern bracket expression, except that the exclamation mark character ( '!' ) shall replace the circumflex character ( '^' ) in its role in a "non-matching list" in the regular expression notation. A bracket expression starting with an unquoted circumflex character produces unspecified results.

That is to say: `[!x]` means the same thing as `[^x]` would mean in a POSIX BRE regular expression -- inverting the character class to match any characters not inside it.

---

To look at the POSIX BRE specification incorporated by reference above (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05):

> In the POSIX locale, a range expression represents the set of collating elements that fall between two elements in the collation sequence, inclusive. In other locales, a range expression has unspecified behavior: strictly conforming applications shall not rely on whether the range expression is valid, or on the set of collating elements matched. A range expression shall be expressed as the starting point and the ending point separated by a hyphen ( '-' ).

That is to say, a hyphen expression includes characters between the start and end points, though this can be modified by the locale locale's collation order, making `[0-9]` an expression that matches digits, albeit bad practice compared to `[[:digit:]]`.

In conjunction with the section above, this means that `[!0-9]` matches any characters which *are not* digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern, not a regular expression. Here is a [reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) that shows the difference.

A pattern is matched with `[[ $var = pattern ]]`, a regular expression is matched using `[[ $var =~ regex ]]`.

The following regex match would be equivalent to your code :

```
if [[ $strin =~ [^0-9] ]]; then
```